# sudo hangs after some time

Tags: linux, sudo, arch-linux

`sudo` hangs in my Archlinux (running under Hyper-V) after some time (usually a day).

Since this hangs my system, I have kept a root window open to do `strace` whenever this happens. `strace sudo ls` shows a `sendto` syscall to a socket called `/dev/log`:

```
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 7
connect(7, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
sendto(7, "<37>Jan 25 20:04:39 sudo:     ro"..., 107, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
```

I can also see some messages in `journalctl -b` that looks like this:

```
Jan 25 18:36:04 archlinux systemd-journald[354638]: Missed 848 kernel messages
Jan 25 18:36:04 archlinux kernel: hv_balloon: Unhandled message: type: 53216
```

Not sure if it is connected to the problem though. Does anyone know what is happening? LTS kernel helped for sometime; but after recent upgrade, even that is not an option.

Comment: This issue has not recurred after turning off **dynamic memory** in Hyper-V. Someone suggested that this might be causing `/dev/log` socket to get killed.